# Can .mp4 files contain viruses?

Tags: virus, file-types

An `.mp4` file is a common file extension which wraps movies, video clips, etc.

Can this file contain viruses?

Or, to rephrase the question, if I open it with a common video player (such as Windows Media Player) can this result in my computer being infected with a virus?

Comment: I wish there was a canonical answer to these questions, because any file could contain a virus. Additionally, nearly any software is capable of containing vulnerabilities. A quick Google search shows vulnerabilities in Windows Media player, some that result from video files: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-26/product_id-1032/Microsoft-Windows-Media-Player.html

Comment: @multithr3at3d I'd be very surprised if a PPM parser was found to be vulnerable.